# Recover the response of my service in another class with retrofit2 in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

*I have a call to my service with retrofit in which I get an answer and I need to send it to another class.*

I have tried to save the response data in a ContentValues ​​and send them by means of a function but this does not work.

```
fun dataEmployee(name: String, numEmp: String): ConsultMovResponse? {
    var cMov = PersonData(name, numEmp)
    var pos: ConsultMovResponse?
    RetrofitClient.instMov.consultMov(cMov).enqueue(object : Callback<ConsultMovResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ConsultMovResponse>, response: Response<ConsultMovResponse>) {
            pos = response?.body()
            //return response, this code does not work.
            return pos?

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ConsultMovResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            println("Error  : " + t.stackTrace.toString())
            println("Error  : " + t.message)
        }
    })
    return pos?
}
```

Comment: Specify your use case, question in not clear

Comment: Thanks for answering. I want to return the value in my main class. Example:class Employeeclass{
  var name="John"
  var numEmp="2112"
  val respondemployeed=dataEmployee(name,numEmp)
  //This is where I want to return the data.
  println("company of the employee"+respondemployeed?.company)

 }

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the response in your activity?, are you following MVP?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I really need to return the response in my activity.

Comment: Then create an interface and get results back to your activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using Retrofit, it'll execute the request asynchronously. This means that before it has a chance to finish the request, the function `dataEmployee` will return an uninitialised `pos`.

There are different ways to go about this, but an easy one is to propagate the callback. Say you define the function as:

```
fun dataEmployee(name: String, numEmp: String, callback: (ConsultMovResponse?) -> Unit)
```

The last argument is a function that should be called when `onResponse` is called. Something like:

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<ConsultMovResponse>, response: Response<ConsultMovResponse>) {
    callback(response?.body())
}
```

The way you can call now the method would be:

```
dataEmployee("Foo", "1234") {
     // Use the implicit parameter `it` which will be the response
}
```

**Edit**
For the error you can follow a similar process. Let's change `dataEmployee` to:

```
fun dataEmployee(name: String, numEmp: String, onSuccess (ConsultMovResponse?) -> Unit, onFailure: (Throwable) -> Unit)
```

On failure you can then call:

```
override fun onFailure(call: Call<ConsultMovResponse>, throwable: Throwable) {
       onFailure(throwable)
}
```

Now you call `dataEmployee` like so:

```
dataEmployee("foo", "1234",
       onSuccess = { /*handle success*/ },
       onFailure = { /*`it` will be the error */ })
```

Comment: similar idea, just add another callback for the error and call it in `onFailure`.

Comment: fun dataEmployee(name: String, numEmp: String, callback: (ConsultMovResponse?) -> Unit,onFailure:(ConsultMovResponse?))

 override fun onFailure(call: Call<ConsultMovResponse>, t: Throwable) {
          onFailure(ConsultMovResponse)
        }

Comment: I´m trying to do it this way.I do not know if it is the correct one. What is the way to call the parameters implicitly?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the problem, I'll edit my answer to help you out